# How to get a Joomla3 template to install the images in a different location-specifically joomlaroot/images?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, images

I've created a Joomla 3 template. When I install the template, I'd like to have the template images automatically install into the `joomlaroot/images` location.
The reason I'd like to do this is because several templates will share the same images. I know I can manually put the images in whatever folder I like, but I'd prefer to have it done automatically when I install the template.

- Is it possible to have a templates images automatically install to
  the joomlaroot/images directory? If yes, how can I do it?
- If no, are there any alternative ways of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you could use an [installer script](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file), and create/copy the files after installation. The problem is that AFAIK templates does not trigger the script.

I suggest you create a [package](https://docs.joomla.org/Package), and then include your template there, because the package installer *should* call the installer script.

Then create your postflight script by adding this to your XML file:

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

And somthing like this in the `script.php` file (not tested):

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class pkg_helloWorldInstallerScript {

    function install($parent) {

        jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

        //change this to the name of the folder you want to create
        $newfolder = 'myfolder';

        if(JFolder::create(JUri::root() . 'images/' . $newfolder)) {        
            //duplicate the line below as many times as you want for each file you want to move
            JFile::move(JUri::root() . 'templates/TEMPLATENAME/images/image.png', JUri::root() . 'images/' . $newfolder);
        }
    }
}    
?>
```

<sup>[Original code by @Lodder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372218/automatically-create-a-folder-and-copy-files-on-installation)</sup>